# Conditional statements using category and Tags

Tags: plugins

I want to use conditional statements in WordPress. How can I get the current category and tag outside of The Loop? I tried this but it did not work for me.

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Codex page for [`get_the_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category):

> This tag may be used outside The Loop by passing a post id as the parameter.

So to use it outside The Loop, you need to do something like:

```
global $post;
$category = get_the_category( $post->ID );
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
```

To get the categories and tags, try [`wp_get_object_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms):

```
global $post;
$id = $post->ID;
$taxonomies = array( 'category', 'post_tag' );
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $id, $taxonomies );
// check what's returned
var_dump( $post_terms );
```

Comment: ok what about tag @pat J

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're viewing a *category or tag archive*, you can access that category or tag object via [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object)

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
echo $queried_object->name;
```